# Matplotlib key_press_event ignored in virtualenv

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, virtualenv

Key press events are not working when matplotlib is being run inside of a virtual environment.

Mac osx Yosemite
backend: MacOSX
matplotlib version: 1.4.3
ipython 2.7.6

I think this has something to do with the readline package not being implemented correctly.

Once a plot is displayed and the figure is in focus, all key presses are still being entered into the terminal. i.e. in this example http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/examples/event_handling/keypress_demo.html it just types `x` into the terminal. <kbd>ESC</kbd>, <kbd>backspace</kbd>, and <kbd>delete</kbd> are registered as their escape characters `^[`, `^H`, `^[[3~`

**Edit:** I can workaround this by [forcing the virtural env to use the framework python](http://www.thebrokendesk.com/post/using-wx-python-in-a-virtual-environment/). However this isn't ideal.

Has anyone run into this before?